# Macbook air stutters during streaming video

Tags: network, macbook-pro, video, streaming

I am streaming video from an ASUS router to a macbook air (2013) and having horrible stuttering problems. No big deal, you may say - I just don't have the bandwidth for it. The only thing is, if I copy the video over the network to my laptop, it only takes 10 minutes for a 90 minute movie, telling me that I have 9X the bandwidth required for streaming. This suggests that buffering may be the problem, but I've used both Movist and VLC and get the same problems.

Has anyone experienced something similar - where more than enough bandwidth is available, but video streaming still stutters horribly? And more importantly, did you find a solution?

Comment: Have you tried having the sender and receiver in the same room. (or preferably linked via ethernet to the router) It *could* be a dropped packet, or interference problem

Comment: Connecting via ethernet or getting close to the router gives flawless streaming, but doesn't really solve the problem. I guess dropped packets could explain it, except that it's still clear that I have 9X the bandwidth for streaming so buffering should handle any dropped packets. I've noticed that network traffic goes in bursts while streaming, whereas it's sustained when copying. I guess I should have also mentioned that the files are on a NAS (directly connected to router).

Comment: Ahh right, So then it looks like either the NAS isn't buffering correctly (very unlikely), there is too much interference to maintain a stream, or VLC isn't actually doing any buffering. I'd wager it's a VLC problem, on the grounds that [this forum post on their own site](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=101969) mentions a "known issue" with streaming directly from NAS. They say to try enabling uPnP, if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the find! Using uPnP from within VLC did the trick.

Comment: Cool stuff! Glad you found it!

Comment: @RossMcKinley you should put your comment as an answer and NubTub should mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a post on VLC's own forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=101969), there is a "known issue" with streaming directly from a NAS.

Here's what they have to say on the streaming from NAS issue.

> "Known issue, but I agree it's really annoying.
>   I also met the lagging issue when playing directly from NAS, but through UPnP, playback is really smooth.
>
> If your NAS has UPnP server, consider using it."

So, the user "nkoriyama" suggests enabling uPnP as the solution, if it's available as an option for you.

Note: *This answer is taken from the comment stream under the op's question*